# firebase tells me that the command "eslint." is either misspelled or could not be found

Tags: firebase, visual-studio

Every time I enter the command in Visaul studio "firebase deploy --only functions".
VisualSTD shows me this error message

"The command "eslint." is either misspelled or
could not be found."

I want to connect firebase to my app and I get this error every time. I do not know what is wrong have already included all other functions with

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint.",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "6.4.17",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

and this is what I get in the Console

```
The command "eslint." is either misspelled or
could not be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint.`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\samo1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-28T15_12_42_887Z-debug.log
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\samo1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\samo1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\samo1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install eslint-cli globally first

```
npm -g i eslint-cli
```

Then in your project folder

```
npm i eslint --save-dev
```